# How to publish message to a channel using Pubnub Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, pubnub, webrtc-ios

currently I'm working on an iOS projects where I need to implement WebRTC with Pubnub signaling. I added the PubNubSwift CocoaPods to my project. And when I try to publish a message the publish method expect the message type as JSONCodable. So I created struct as follows,

```
struct sdpPacket: Codable {
    var type: String?
    var sdp: String?
}

struct sdpDataPacket: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var packet: sdpPacket?
    var number: String?
}
```

and in the publish method I added these lines,

```
let sdpPacketVal = sdpPacket(type: "offer", sdp: sdp.description)
let packet = sdpDataPacket(id: uuid, packet: sdpPacketVal, number: self.PubnubChannel)
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(packet)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
        
self.appDelegate.pubnub.publish(channel: channelName, message: jsonString) { result in
   print(result.map { "Publish Response at \($0.timetoken.timetokenDate)" })
}
```

But in the response, I'm getting result as

```
failure(The request contained a malformed JSON payload)
```

I will show the jsonString

```
{
   "id":"userUUID",
   "packet":{
      "type":"offer",
      "sdp":"RTCSessionDescription:\noffer\nv=0\r\no=- 7871361170753072042 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS RTCmS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:PYqe\r\na=ice-"
   },
   "number":"userPubnubName"
}
```

I don't know what is the error in my code.
Please help me.

Comment: Does the `sdp` field contain any non-standard unicode characters? Would it be possible to try to encode it using `base64` before sending?

Comment: Yes inside sdp, I'm passing sdp description. So it contains unicode characters.

Comment: According to the docs at: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe you should not be converting to string "Do Not Use JSON.stringify!
It is important to note that you should not use JSON.stringify() when sending signals/messages via PubNub. Why? Because the serialization is done for you automatically. Instead just pass the full object as the message payload. PubNub takes care of everything for you."

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your base encoding the object.

You need is pass in the Swift object.

```
let sdpPacketVal = sdpPacket(type: "offer", sdp: sdp.description)
let packet = sdpDataPacket(id: uuid, packet: sdpPacketVal, number: self.PubnubChannel)
self.appDelegate.pubnub.publish(channel: channelName, message: jsonString) { result in
   print(result.map { "Publish Response at \($0.timetoken.timetokenDate)" })
}
```

And then make the two payload objects implement JSONCodable

```
struct sdpPacket: JSONCodable {
    var type: String?
    var sdp: String?
}
struct sdpDataPacket: JSONCodable {
    var id: String?
    var packet: sdpPacket?
    var number: String?
}
```